# How can I increase the amount of drag down in SwipeRefreshLayout?

Tags: java, android, swiperefreshlayout

I have one SwipeRefreshLayout and I want to increase the amount of drag down.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
val dp = 100
swipeRefreshLayout.setDistanceToTriggerSync(dp)

public void setDistanceToTriggerSync (int distance)
Set the distance to trigger a sync in dips
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setProgressViewOffset` method.
e.g

```
val offset: Int = 70 //you can set value according to your requirement
swipeRefreshLayout.setProgressViewOffset(false, 0, offset)
```